# pypyodbc connects with explicit string but not variable

Tags: python, odbc, wxpython, pypyodbc

I'm reading a connection string for an SQL Server database from the user, represented by randomstring here. When I print randomstring to the console it looks perfectly formed, and I've been over it a dozen times to check. However, the connection fails with

pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft]

If I explicitly pass the exact same string to the cursor, the connection works fine. Do I need to do anything specific with the string variable to be able to use it ?

```
    randomstring = ShowConnString(self.cframe).connstringtext
    print(randomstring)
    self.conn = pypyodbc.connect(randomstring)
    #self.conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='password')
```

Edit: print (randomstring) outputs:

pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='password')

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what appears in the console when you `print(randomstring)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your second (commented out) example is not connecting with an "explicit [connection] string", it is using a series of *keyword arguments* ("kwargs") to specify `driver`, `server`, etc.. Note the subtle difference between the keyword arguments form ...

```python
self.conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='password')
```

... and the connection string form:

```python
self.conn = pypyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server};server=(local);database=Audit;uid=sa;pwd=password')
```

Now if your `randomstring` variable really does contain

```
pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='password')
```

then it is definitely not a valid ODBC connection string. Even if it just contained

```
driver='{SQL Server}', server='(local)', database='Audit', uid='sa', pwd='password'
```

that would still not be a valid connection string because the items are separated by commas (not semicolons) and there are quotes around the values. You will need to transform the contents of your `randomstring` value into a proper ODBC connection string before you pass it to the `.connect` method.

Comment: randomstring is now outputting

driver={SQL Server};server=(local);database=Audit;uid=sa;pwd=password

but I'm still getting the same error with self.conn - pypyodbc.connect(randomstring) but with the following explicit call it works:

 self.conn = pypyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server};server=(local);database=GermanAudit;uid=sa;pwd=_PWD4sa_')

I don't get it

Comment: Actually, I think the value of the text box is being returned with a newline character in front of it, when I print it out to the console it's one line down from the top of the console screen